# Throw an error if update operation did not suceed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have following update logic for one of my collections

```
  async update(uid, data, version) {
    const filter = { _id: new ObjectId(uid), version }
    const update = { $set: data, $inc: { version: 1 } }
    const result = await myCollection.updateOne(filter, update)

    if (!result.acknowledged) {
      throw new Error('Errored')
    }
  },
```

Idea here is to update document only if it matches provided version, however after few experiments with invalid version I am unable to get this function to throw an error.

I get following results for *invalid* request

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 0
}
```

and following for *valid* request

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

I was expecting mongo to throw an error or return `acknowledged: false` if update was not possible. Is the only way to throw here a check for `modifiedCount: 0`? Or am I missing some settings / using incorrect action?

Comment: I think [the answer from @go_sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74211042/20042973) is correct. What constitutes an _invalid_ request, one that doesn't modify any documents? That's still a valid request to the database, hence the successful acknowledgement of processing the operation (and finding nothing to update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with mongodb, but an example I found in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#update-using-update-operator-expressions) shows that if no matches are found, the operation can return
`acknowledged: true`
So you have to check if `matchedCount` and `modifiedCount` are `0`.